# Why do convex combinations of a subset stay within a convex set which contains the subset?

Tags: convex-analysis

If we are working over a general topological vector space V (i.e. not necessarily $R^d$) and we consider a subset $A \subset V$ which itself it not necessarily convex and a convex set $G$ which contains $A$, why is it that any convex combination

$$
t_1x_1 + ... + t_nx_n
$$

of elements $x_1, ..., x_n \in A$ and $t_i \in (0,1)$ with the sum of the $t_i's$ being equal to $1$ is an element of $G$?  Intuitively it makes enough sense, since we are sort of 'filling out' the convex set $G$ by lines drawn between finitely many points $x_k$ in $A$, but is there a simple way of proving that any convex combination like above will be an element of $G$?

Comment: Can you prove it for $n = 2$?  for $n = 3$?  for $n = k+1$ if it is true for $n = k$?  It might help to write $t_n$ as $1 - (t_1 + \cdots + t_{n-1})$.  Also, are you familiar with the definition of "convex hull"?

Comment: The easiest way is by induction and you can choose the $t_i \in [0,1]$ as long as they sum to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Any convex combination of elements of $G$ will be inside $G$.

Since $x_i \in A$ and $A$ is a subset of $G$, $x_i \in G$.

Hence the convex combination is in $G$.